# Add a 5 minutes Countdown timer to a quiz website developed in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, timer, countdowntimer

I need to implement a countdown timer for a quiz in a Spring boot webApp.I tried to implement it using JS but every time the user clicks on the next question button the timer resets. the timer must be of five minutes and at 00:00 the quiz must be auto-submitted.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

In past I have implemented something similar, It was for learning purpose. On server-side I have created cookie for user and session, then I have stored start time in session for this user. So refreshing website would just pick up start time from user session kept on server. As for auto-submit functionality, you would need to implement It on the frontend side. Using JS you can check whether time has reached 00:00, and run function that performs submit.